# Strange results with Path.startsWith()

Tags: java, path, nio

Can anyone explain the following result?

```
Path p = Paths.get("/a/b");
System.out.println(p.startsWith(p.subpath(0, 1)));
```

Output:

```
false
```

I would expect it to be true, since the path begins with the first element of the path.

Comment: What do you see if you print out p and p.subpath(0, 1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`subpath` returns a relative path.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#subpath%28int,%20int%29) An absolute path `/a/b`, does not start with a relative path `a`.

But a relative path `a/b` does start with a relative path `a`.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't appreciated that subtlety.